# receiving signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault when running a node

Tags: ros-kinetic, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I getting "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error when running a node, despite the fact that it worked well before

when I run it with gdb I'm getting this

```
Starting program: /home/jafar/catkin_ws/devel/lib/kuka_arm/trajectory_sampler 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7fffd8257700 (LWP 3192)]
[New Thread 0x7fffd7a56700 (LWP 3193)]
[New Thread 0x7fffd7255700 (LWP 3194)]
[New Thread 0x7fffd6a54700 (LWP 3199)]
[New Thread 0x7fffd6253700 (LWP 3200)]
[New Thread 0x7fffd5a52700 (LWP 3213)]

Thread 1 "trajectory_samp" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff55d8f18 in ros::WallTime::now() ()
from /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/librostime.so
```

Anyone know why this's happening ..?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/303425/receiving-signal-sigsegv,-segmentation-fault-when-running-a-node/) by [jafar_abdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25259/jafar_abdi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 221 on 2018-09-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There have been a nr of reports of ABI breakages with Kinetic after the last sync.

Have you rebuilt your workspace recently and/or upgraded all packages?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jafar_abdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25259/jafar_abdi/) on 2018-09-15**:
It worked after I run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```